# In SwiftUI, what's the difference between .modifier and .layout

Tags: swiftui

I cannot seem to find any difference between applying a ViewModifier using either **.modifier** or **.layout**. They both produce the same result. Anyone knows what's the difference between these two. There's no documentation whatsoever.

For example, given this modifier:

```swift
struct RedTitle: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        return content.foregroundColor(.red).font(.title)
    }
}
```

These two views turn out to look identical:

```swift
Text("Hello world!").layout(RedTitle())
```

```swift
Text("Hello world!").modifier(RedTitle())
```

Comment: Good question. Looking into the definitions in Xcode, they look extremely similar. Remembering that this is beta 2, let's hope they either clarify things or eliminate one before GM.

Comment: There're so many holes in the documentation. Let's hope you're right!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### UPDATE

As of Xcode 11 beta 4, the `layout` modifier has been marked deprecated:

```
extension View {
  @available(*, deprecated, renamed: "modifier")
  @inlinable public func layout<T>(_ layout: T) -> some SwiftUI.View where T : SwiftUI.ViewModifier {
        return modifier(layout)
    }
}
```

### ORIGINAL

There is no difference as of Xcode 11 beta 2. That doesn't mean there will always be no difference. Possibly `layout` is left over from an older design and needs to be removed, or perhaps a later beta will make it behave differently.

The complete interface exported by SwiftUI can be found in this file:

```
/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/Modules/SwiftUI.swiftmodule/arm64.swiftinterface
```

Looking in that file, you can find the declaration of `func modifier`:

```
extension View {
  public typealias Modified<T> = _ModifiedContent<Self, T> where T : SwiftUI.ViewModifier
  @inlinable public func modifier<T>(_ modifier: T) -> Modified<T> where T : SwiftUI.ViewModifier {
        return .init(content: self, modifier: modifier)
    }
}
```

And the declaration of `func layout`:

```
extension View {
  @inlinable public func layout<T>(_ layout: T) -> Modified<T> where T : SwiftUI.ViewModifier {
        return modifier(layout)
    }
}
```

Because both `modifier` and `layout` are declared `@inlinable`, Swift includes the function bodies in the `.swiftinterface` file. We can see that `layout` just calls `modifier` and does nothing else.

Comment: I'll keep using **.modifier**. It was mentioned during the WWDC, but **layout** was not, so I think it is more future proof.